# How do I randomly select lines from a file based on a character in Unix?

Tags: unix

I would like to randomly select lines from a file based on the first few characters in the line. In my files, the first few characters are named "Hybrid: 2", "Hybrid: 19", etc. I would like to randomly select only one representative line from each Hybrid category.

**I have a file formatted like this:**

```
Hybrid: 2 Parents: 12 and 49     9.419642 0.000000
Hybrid: 2 Parents: 15 and 49     6.427708 0.000000
Hybrid: 2 Parents: 16 and 49     8.383469 0.000000
Hybrid: 2 Parents: 17 and 49     7.869732 0.000000
Hybrid: 19 Parents: 2 and 23     6.905067 0.000000
Hybrid: 19 Parents: 2 and 30     7.913185 0.000000
Hybrid: 19 Parents: 2 and 57     10.724088 0.000000
Hybrid: 52 Parents: 2 and 23     9.398697 0.000000
Hybrid: 44 Parents: 2 and 30     7.739156 0.000000
Hybrid: 50 Parents: 2 and 30     10.051190 0.000000
```

**And I would like to make files like this:**

```
Hybrid: 2 Parents: 15 and 49     6.427708 0.000000
Hybrid: 19 Parents: 2 and 23     6.905067 0.000000
Hybrid: 52 Parents: 2 and 23     9.398697 0.000000
Hybrid: 44 Parents: 2 and 30     7.739156 0.000000
Hybrid: 50 Parents: 2 and 30     10.051190 0.000000
```

I thought shuf would be useful, but I can't see how to apply it here. I'm not sure how to approach this, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the unique lines (Hybrid 19,Hybrid 52,Hybrid 44,Hybrid 50,Hybrid 2). After this shuffle the file. Shuffle will return a random permutation of lines in the file. Get the first line of the shuffled file.

The Code to do this is below

Copy the below script to a file say`UniqueLines.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

filePath=$1
cat $filePath | awk '{print $2}' | uniq > /tmp/unique_ids
for i in `cat /tmp/unique_ids`;do shuf file.txt | grep "Hybrid: $i " | head -1;done;
```

Grant Permission to Run the Script

```
chmod +x UniqueLines.sh
```

Run the Script

```
./UniqueLines.sh <full path to file>

Example:
./UniqueLines.sh /root/myfile.txt
```